# With Guice, how to access injected class name

Tags: guice, slf4j

I'm trying to inject slf4j logger through Guice DI. So far, I implemented the easy way; I've bound `Logger.class` to the slf4j root logger.

Right now, I'm trying to do it the right way, and inject the class name into the `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` method. However, I'm not sure how I can access the name of the class being injected.

I've seen an [example using field injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/CustomInjections#example-injecting-a-log4j-logger), but I haven't found any example that does it using constructor injection.

Can it be done?

**Edit:**
I've stopped trying to do any magic and I simply inject the `LoggerFactory` instance (A wrapper over it in fact). It simplifies everything and it allows me to get whichever `Logger` instance I need for a particular class.

Comment: You can do this in Guice 4 with a project I wrote called `sangria-contextual` (and there's even a pre-packaged SLF4J solution `sangria-slf4j`).  Blog post [here](https://tavianator.com/announcing-sangria/), GitHub [here](https://github.com/tavianator/sangria).

Comment: Is there a way, within 30 lines of code and without a third party, to achieve this?

Comment: 30 lines might be pushing it, but I'll write up the technique in an answer when I have time.  The trick is to use `ProvisionListener` and a `ThreadLocal`.